# Cypher: how to find last node in a variable path with array argument?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph structure:

labels: Building, BuildingHier

BuildingHier can be for example room or floor. (but its variable).

relations:

`(h:BuildingHier({key: 'floor', value: 3})-[:PART_OF]->(b:Building({id: 'myid'})`

`(h1:BuildingHier({key: 'room', value: 40})-[:PART_OF]->(h2:BuildingHier({key: 'floor', value: 3})`

lets say I have a tags array `[{key: 'room', value: 49},{key: 'floor', value: '3'}]` of a new node which I want to connect. how can I find the last node in path (the room node) ?

the hierarchies are dynamic, floor and room are just examples and there can be additional hierarchies such as wing.

EDIT:
the building, floors and rooms are connected. I want to connect a new node to the relevant room, for example an asset with tags array as in the example. I want to find the last node (room 49) in correct path in the graph (building -> floor 3 -> room 49) to connect it to..
I need to find the (variable length) path that meets all conditions

Comment: Can you expand on what it is you'd like to add - do you want to add two more nodes with the properties in the array you listed above? And if so, what do you mean by "finding the room node" in that context - shouldn't you want to find the :Building node to attach those two to?

Comment: @jakewins I edited the question with further explanation.

Comment: Can you add a picture of your graph?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I get the domain model, can you add some psuedo code or even better what have you tried so far?

> I want to find the last node (room 49) in correct path in the graph (building -> floor 3 -> >room 49) to connect it to

Why not just query for it ? Why the "last node in the path" ?

```
MATCH (room:BuildingHier { key:"room",value:49 })-[:PART_OF]->(floor:BuildingHier { key:"floor",value:3 })-[:PART_OF]-(building:Building { id:"1" }) return room,floor,building;
```

you can then add multiple MERGE/CREATE commands

```
MERGE (someotherpart:BuldingHier { key:"someptherparts",value:121 })-[:PART_OF]-(room)
```

If you dont have the key/values to query but want to search down of a given depth given a known branch and its relationship you could do something like

```
MATCH (something)-[r:PART_OF*1..2]->(building:Building)
RETURN building,something;
```

To get the last value in that chain you can use

```
MATCH (something)-[r:PART_OF*1..2]->(building:Building)
RETURN last(collect(something.value));
```

Or is the problem on how to extract the tag key/values and add as parameters to the cypher command ? What language/driver are you using.

the Cypher reference card is your best friend =)
http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/

Comment: I can't use `MATCH (room:BuildingHier { key:"room",value:49 })-[:PART_OF]->(floor:BuildingHier { key:"floor",value:3 })-[:PART_OF]-(building:Building { id:"1" }) return room,floor,building;` because the hierarchies are are dynamic (eg: wing, floor, room, or just room). I also don't know if the array is ordered by the structure of hierarchies. what I need is to find the path which contains all nodes with the correct key/value properties.

Comment: just searching for `{key: 'room', value: 49}` with a variable length PART_OF path isn't enough as it doesn't guarantee the correct floor..

Comment: maybe it can be done with something like `MATCH (b:Building {id: ..})<-[:PART_OF*1..]-(x:BuildingHier)...` and have all returned x nodes key and value properties match those of the given tags array ?

Comment: It is a rather hard domain model you got there, i am not sure you can do all that in one go. The last solution sounds good MATCH (b:Building { id:"1" })<-[:PART_OF*1..]-(x:BuildingHier)
WITH collect(x.key) AS KeyColl,collect(x.value) AS ValueColl
RETURN filter(x IN KeyColl 
              WHERE x = "room"), filter(y IN ValueColl 
                                        WHERE y = 49);
But i dont know how you would do that with an array of key/values.

Comment: Mabey handle and to the kV comparision it on the application side ? With something like
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((something)-[r:PART_OF]->(building:Building { id:"1" }))
RETURN extract(x IN nodes(p)| x.key) AS Key, extract(x IN nodes(p)| x.value) AS Value;

Comment: what can be a better model for this? I need dynamic hierarchies (like floors -> rooms, or wings -> floors -> rooms), but each building has its own hierarchy structure.